# Free draw inside a fabric.Image.fromURL

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to able free draw on a **FabricJS** library.

But i need to limit user free draw on a previously loaded *fabric.image*.

Testing with a *fabric.Text* to add text on a canvas, i have a text property called **globalCompositeOperation**, setted as source-atop it works, the text only can showed inside the previous loaded fabric.Image. But i can't do it with free draw.

I try to use **globalCompositeOperation** on *canvas.freeDrawingBrush*, but doesn't work.

Can you help me?

Lot of thanks!

You can look the issue here: https://www.irealworks.com/miniworks/fabricjs/

Click on **Add text** to look the correct usage.

Click on **Draw on/off** to look that you can draw outside the bottle. I want draw inside bottle limits.

And that's the code:

````
    <body>
        <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="fabricjs.js"></script>
        <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <button id="btnAddText" >Add Text</button>
        <button id="btnDraw" >Draw on / off</button>
        <button id="btnImg" >To image</button>

        <br clear="all" />
        <br clear="all" />

        <img id="backgroundHide" src="background.png" style="display:none">
        <img id="bottleHide" src="botella.png" style="display:none">

        <div id="bottleBackground" style="border:1px solid; background-image:url('background.png'); position:relative; background-size: contain; background-repeat:no-repeat; float:left;">
            <canvas id="canvasBottle"></canvas>
        </div>

        <script>

            var drawing = false;

            $(function(){

                let canvasWidth = 500,
                    canvasHeight = 500;

                $('#canvasBottle').css({
                    width: canvasWidth,
                    height: canvasHeight
                });

                var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvasBottle', {
                    width: $("#canvasBottle").width(),
                    height: $("#canvasBottle").height()
                });

                $('#btnImg').click(function(){

                    html2canvas(document.getElementById('bottleBackground')).then(function(canvas2) {
                        console.log(canvas2.toDataURL("png"));
                    });

                });
                $("#btnAddText").click(function () {
                    var text = new fabric.Text("Testing", {
                        fontSize: 50,
                        fill: "green",
                        top: 100,
                        left: 100
                    });
                    canvas.add(text);
                    text.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    canvas.renderAll();
                });

                $('#btnDraw').click(function(){
                    canvas.isDrawingMode = !canvas.isDrawingMode;
                });

                canvas.freeDrawingBrush = new fabric.PencilBrush(canvas);
                canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = '#000';
                canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 10;
                canvas.freeDrawingBrush.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop'; /* Not Work! */

                var background;

                fabric.Image.fromURL('botella.png', function (objects, options) {
                    background = objects;

                    let percentTopBottle = 15.9354,
                        percentLeftBottle = 29.6129,
                        borderCanvas = 2,
                        backgroundRealWidth = $('#backgroundHide').width(),
                        backgroundRealHeight = $('#backgroundHide').height(),
                        bottleRealWidth = $('#bottleHide').width(),
                        bottleRealHeight = $('#bottleHide').height(),
                        bottleWMax = canvas.width * (((bottleRealWidth * 100) / backgroundRealWidth) / 100),
                        bottleHMax = canvas.height * (((bottleRealHeight * 100) / backgroundRealHeight) / 100),
                        scaleX = bottleWMax / background.width,
                        scaleY = bottleHMax / background.height,
                        topBottle = ((backgroundRealWidth * (percentTopBottle / 100)) * scaleX) - borderCanvas,
                        leftBottle = ((backgroundRealHeight * (percentLeftBottle / 100)) * scaleY) - borderCanvas;

                    background.set({
                        top: topBottle,
                        left: leftBottle,
                        scaleX: scaleX,
                        scaleY: scaleY,
                        selectable: false,
                        id: 'main'
                    });

                    canvas.add(background);
                    canvas.renderAll();

                });

            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having the same problem..